# Programmatically Log/Tail Browser Activity with Ruby to a File?

Tags: ruby, logging, browser

How do I access this activity log information programmatically with Ruby (this is the Activity Window from Safari)?  Can I use Mechanize to spit out all this information (duration, size, address, etc.) in XML, or is this already stored somewhere on my computer?

[image]
<sub>(source: [boogdesign.com](http://www.boogdesign.com/images/safari/safari_activity.png))</sub>

Comment: Obviously, it's stored on your computer, but the details vary per OS and per browser maker/version.  You might consider using a proxy instead, which will work anywhere. See https://github.com/evaryont/mousehole

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about your Ruby on Rails logs they are located in

```
RAILS_ROOT/log
```

And then each is broken out by environment, you should have one log each for development, production, etc.

If you're on windows you might want to look at [RubyLogParser](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubylogparser) which wraps Microsoft's Log Parser. Personally, I'd grep the heck out log to extract what information I wanted and then use ruby for higher level analysis and display of that data.

Comment: I'm looking at just tracking all of the sites I go to in a browser, not rails sites I'm developing. Can I access that info or log file programmatically?